Meaning of letter K in chemistry conventions
The letter "K" is usually used as chemistry (or statistics/ physics) conventions, take the equilibrium constant (Kc) and rate constant (k) as two prime examples.
Are there any reasons why "K" is often used? Or, to ask more specifically, what does "K" mean in "Kc"?

Because the German words for 'constant' and 'coefficient' start with the letter 'K'.

There were times when US and English were not hegemons in physics and chemistry, but Germany was, especially between 1871 and 1914, sponsored by big war reparations paid by France.

$K$ in thermodynamics isn't $k$ in chemical kinetics.  $K$ is more general, while for instance $K_c$ is specific about molar concentrations, $K_p$ about partial pressures, and $K_a$ about chemical activities of the species involved.  If you like to know more about their use, see IUPAC's Green Book (or/and its summary) linked in section nomenclature of the resources page.
